# Issue with sending packet via ZMQ

Tags: c++, zeromq, gnuradio-companion

I have the following C++ code that sends a zmq packet of 10 bytes to a ZMQ Pull Source in GNU Radio Companion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zmq.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    void *send_context, *responder;
    unsigned short gnu_trigger[10];
    string trig_addr = "tcp://127.0.0.1:4500";
    int rc;

    /* Bind ZMQ address for transmitting data */
    send_context = zmq_ctx_new();
    responder = zmq_socket(send_context, ZMQ_PUSH);
    rc = zmq_bind(responder, trig_addr.c_str());
    
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Sending trigger to gnuradio\n";
    
        memset(gnu_trigger, 0x0, sizeof(unsigned short) * 10);
        gnu_trigger[0] = 1;
        
        rc = zmq_send(responder, &gnu_trigger, sizeof(gnu_trigger), 0);
    
        cout << "Sent trigger to gnuradio\n";
        sleep(1);
    }

    zmq_close(responder);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(send_context);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove/comment the cout statements before and after sending the ZMQ packets, the packet is not transmitted. However, if the cout statements are enabled, the packet is sent successfully.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Zmq is asynchronous so messages aren't sent when you call `zmq_send` and are sent at some point in the future. As your program ends immediately after calling `zmq_send` zmq doesn't have time to send the messages.

Adding the print statements slows your program down enough to allow zmq time to send the messages.

You should call [`zmq_close`](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-close) and [`zmq_term`](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-term) before exiting your program.

Comment: In the actual code, the program doesn't end after sending the packet. And I am also calling zmq close there as well. I just forgot to include it in the question. So would there be any other explanation?

Comment: In that case please show a [mre]

Comment: You should also check the result and error code for [zmq_send](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-send)

Comment: I have updated the code to give a reproducible example.

Comment: Since I am calling zmq_send as a blocking function, I am assuming that the function will not return until it transmits all of the data. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: If you look at the error codes you'll probably find out why the send is failing

Comment: The send doesnt exactly fail. It is configured as blocking and gets blocked because it is unable to send the packet.